# How to include a javascript in Asciidoc?

Tags: javascript, asciidoc

I'm using asciidoctor-maven-plugin to convert .adoc files to html file...
Would want to include a link to javascript in the generated html file...
Basically would like to see something like below in the html file that is generated from the .adoc file

```
<script src="custom.js"></script>
```

Tried setting attributes like linkcss scriptsdir etc..but of no luck...

Any help?

One way is like in
http://mrhaki.blogspot.ie/2014/06/awesome-asciidoc-include-raw-html.html

But then have to add it in every .adoc file...is there a way to get it automatically added just like the CSS (using stylesheet)

Comment: This? http://asciidoctor.org/docs/install-and-use-asciidoctorjs/

Comment: @Diodeus That's not what the question's asking. OP, have you tried just escaping the `<>`? See here for info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692123/escape-tags-in-html

Comment: I've edited your question to make code visible. Next time don't forget to check what you're about to post in the bottom preview panel ;-)

Answer (score 13):

You can use the passthrough block for that using `++++`:

```
++++
<p>
Content in a passthrough block is passed to the output unprocessed.
That means you can include raw HTML, like this embedded Gist:
</p>

<script src="http://gist.github.com/mojavelinux/5333524.js">
</script>
++++
```

Source: http://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoc-syntax-quick-reference/#more-delimited-blocks

Comment: Though it works, there's a limitation that you can't pass any values inside this block.

Answer (score 12):

Use docinfo files, [see the documentation for more detail](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#docinfo-file).

You create docinfo files by adding another file named `<doc_file_name>-docinfo.html` for HTML generation or `<doc_file_name>-docinfo.xml` for docbook generation. The contents of the docinfo file are copied into the generated output, in the `head` section for html. If you want to add things to the bottom of the document there are footer docinfo files for that. It follows the same as a normal docinfo but the file name is `<doc_file_name>-docinfo-footer.html` or `<doc_file_name>-docinfo-footer.xml`

Happy docing :) Let me, or preferably [the list](http://discuss.asciidoctor.org/) know of any other maven issues you find.

Comment: And don't forget to set the :docinfo: attribute in your adoc, to the corresponding value! (also explained in the docs linked by @LightGuard)